# How can I concisely display a list of table columns in sorted order in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know I can get the list of columns for a table displayed in sorted order by executing this long sql command (in this case from the table 'orders'):

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'orders'
order by column_name;
```

How can this be done most concisely? For example, if the built-in \d command accepted a flag, it could be:

\d -s orders

Naturally, this doesn't work, but I'd like something similar to avoid having to type in the entire original query above repeatedly. Maybe defining a function that can be invoked concisely that's parameterized by table name?

Comment: Your query is reasonably concise already. What's the problem with using it?

Comment: Yes, by creating a function!

Comment: @Bohemian I'd rather not type that entire query in every time I want to display a list of columns in sorted order in psql. You and I may differ on what we feel is "concise".

Comment: @Houari what would that function look like?

Comment: @BrianAdkins a function will looks like `SELECT * FROM my_function('public','orders');`, If you have a problem with the creation of this kind of function, please show what did you try untill now by updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

The raw query is about as terse as it can be. To minimise the typing effort of using it, create a view (with a short name):

```
create view cols as
select column_name, table_name tab
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public'
order by column_name
```

Then to use it:

```
select * from cols where tab = 'mytable'
```

Note how (with postgres) you can define a view with an order (saving you from typing the order by every time).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but it is my current solution to the problem. I use the shell:

```
psql -t db_name -c '\d table_name' | sort
```

This prints out a sorted list of columns which makes discovering schema easier on that random remote system. With the added benefit of not having to remember any arbitrary sql.